# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: react-native

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve net.minidev:json-smart:[1.3.1,2.3].
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-code-push > com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.1
> > Failed to list versions for net.minidev:json-smart.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)

i am getting above error while building project . unable to resolve it please help me out.

Answer (score 8):

Try to fix it by changing in `react-native-code-push`

> node-module/react-native-code-push/android/app/build.gradle

edit line

```
implementation('com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.1')
```

to

```
implementation('com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.1') 
 { exclude group: "net.minidev", module: "json-smart" }
```

Try another [Solution](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1448#issuecomment-1120735821) if the above don't work

Complete [Solution Stack](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1448)

Comment: This will cause crashes with new code push update.

Comment: **Never** edit vendor code files

Answer (score 5):

Adding `MavenCentral()` to the Android `build.gradle` IMO is a cleaner solution and it worked for me!

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
```

Answer (score 0):

It save my life :D, with react native 0.59 & codepush 5.6

implementation('com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.1')
{ exclude group: "net.minidev", module: "json-smart" }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"react-native": "^0.63.3" & "react-native-code-push": "6.4.0"
This solution works:
/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/build.gradle
Change to:
implementation('com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.1')
{ exclude group: "net.minidev", module: "json-smart" }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).